# How to start IDLE that comes with Python 3.6

Tags: linux-mint

I am using [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 18. I installed Python 3.5 and 3.6 using *[apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))* in the terminal. I can open [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) of Python 2.7 and 3.5 using commands *idle* and *idle3* respectively. How can I access IDLE that comes with Python 3.6?

Comment: Did you get the solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

Try the command `idle3.6`. `python3` and `idle3` are still associated with your system Python, which is 3.5.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Simply typing in `idle3.6` should work just like [carusot42 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003141/how-to-start-idle-that-comes-with-python-3-6/42003521#42003521). If it doesn't work, perhaps you might want to see if everything else is installed correctly. Here are the steps I followed which worked perfectly fine for me. I am also running Linux Mint 18. The steps that I followed were:

- Installed the prerequisites of Python. Do that by typing in the following commands -

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
  sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
  ```
- Download [Python](http://www.python.org) using the following command and extract it (use your desired location) -

  ```
  cd /usr/src
  wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
  sudo tar xzf Python-3.6.0.tgz
  ```
- The next step is to compile Python source. To do that type in the commands below-

  ```
  cd Python-3.6.1
  ./configure
  sudo make altinstall
  ```

  `make altinstall` is used to prevent replacing the default Python binary
  file `/usr/bin/python`

You should be good to go. You check your Python version by typing `python3.6 -V` in the terminal.

Once you do that, type in `idle3.6` and then *Python 3.6.1 shell* should open for you.

Comment: did you mean:  sudo tar xzf Python-3.6.1.tgz

Answer (score 1):

The Software Manager in Linux Mint lists the Python Packages and IDLE Packages 
separately.  After you install Python, go look up the associated IDLE package in the Software Manager and install it.  Reboot and it should work fine.  It worked for me.