# Python - response.read() runs smoothly in Windows but not at all in Raspbian

Tags: python, windows, raspbian, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to run the program which uses Microsoft Emotion API program here in my raspberry pi3. 
I tried it on Windows on version Python3.6.4 and it runs perfectly alright. 
However, when I try it on Raspberrypi3, using the default python3.5 (which does not have http.client) AND also python3.6.2 IDLE ([How to start IDLE that comes with Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003141/how-to-start-idle-that-comes-with-python-3-6)), the program either (1) does NOT run at all, (2) or gives a time-out error, (3) or a

```
b'{"error":{"code":"InvalidImageSize","message":"Image size is too small or too big."}}' error.
```

I have also tried to run it on python3.6 under env environment but to no avail. It did not even print happiness which is supposed to return a float value. Please advice why and how can I make it work on Raspberry Pi, thank you very much! Have it got to do with the python version? The API?

The codes are as follows:

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64, sys
import json


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MY-KEY',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        })

body = open('1.jpg','rb').read()

print ('begin')
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
print ('connection')
conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)
print ('request')
response = conn.getresponse()
print ('donerequest')
data = response.read()
print(data)

faces = json.loads(data)
happiness = faces[0]['scores']['happiness'] if len(faces)>0 else 0
print (happiness)
with open('result.txt', 'a') as out:
    out.write("1"+ '\n')
conn.close()
```

Problem: 
stops at `print(data)`: `b'{"error":{"code": "timeout", "message": "the operation was timeout." }}'
Traceback (most recent call last): File.... in line 31 in <module> 
happiness = faces[0]['scores']['happiness'] if len(faces)>0 else 0 keyerror: 0.`

It seems that the problem happens at 
data = response.read() as print(data) returns with "operation is timeout" error". May I know how should I edit it in raspbian as it works well in windows for that?
I did try the following to no avail:

```
data = response.read().decode("utf8")
```

Comment: `try / except:
    pass` is a very bad way of catching exceptions. Try to narrow down the type of exceptions you want to catch

Comment: "Does not run" is not a helpful feedback.  When you executed your script in terminal what happens? I have a feeling it's running alright, just that something within the `try` block failed and your `except` is not showing any meaningful feedback, so it *looks* like your program is not running.  But in reality, it is, and it's gone straight to the `except: pass` line and did nothing of note.

Comment: If you have a debugger, use it.  Otherwise, one manual way to debug this is adding some `print` statements into your program so *before* you reach the `try` block, you can say `print('begin try')` and see if it ever reaches that point.  Likewise, add `print('begin connection')`, `print('reading response')`... etc.  See where your program actually stopped.  It may very likely be a connection issue.  Also, change your `except` line to `except Exception as e: print(e)` and see what errors you are getting.  Or better yet, don't do a `try/except` and simply see what errors return.  Go from there.

Comment: @Idlehands Thank you both for the suggestion! I have re-edited my codes and the IDLE stopsat print(data): b'{"error":{"code": "timeout", "message": "the operation was timeout." line 31 in <module> happiness = faces[0]['scores']['happiness'] if len(faces)>0 else 0 keyerror: 0. It seems that the problem happens at 
data = response.read() as print(data) returns with "operation is timeout" error". how should I edit it in raspbian as it works well in windows for that

Comment: That could be a server response (which means server related) or your RPI have connection issues.  Have you performed a speed test or tried requesting different pages on your RPI and see if you get a proper response? Could also be the data you're POSTING is taking longer than expected to send to the server.  At this point it's hard to say why exactly it's timing out.